# looping through dictionary of inconsistent lists

Tags: python, for-loop, dictionary

I am parsing  xml and converting it to dictionary. 
there by my dictionary will look like

```
'directories': {'dirname': 'D:\\directory\\subdir'},
```

or

```
'directories': {   'dirname': [   'D:\\directory1\\subdir1',
                                  'D:\\directory2\\subdir2']},
```

how to loop through this dictionary. 
currently I am doing like this which works good only if it has multiple elements. Should I check if `dirname` is a list of elements or just a element and there by looping through ? Or is there any pythonic way to achieve this

```
rules = []
for v in args["directories"]["dirname"]:
    rules.append(os.path.join(v, "*", "*"))
```

Output: 
for input `'directories': {   'dirname': [   'D:\\directory1\\subdir1',
                                      'D:\\directory2\\subdir2']},`

```
  rules[] = ['D:\\directory1\\subdir1\\*\\*', 'D:\\directory1\\subdir1\\*\\*']
```

for input `'directories': {'dirname': 'D:\\directory\\subdir'},`

```
['D\\*\\*', ':\\*\\*', '\\*\\*', 'd\\*\\*', 'i\\*\\*', 'r\\*\\*', 'e\\*\\*', 'c\\*\\*', 't\\*\\*', 'o\\*\\*', 'r\\*\\*', 'y\\*\\*', '\\*\\*', 's\\*\\*', 'u\\*\\*', 'b\\*\\*', 'd\\*\\*', 'i\\*\\*', 'r\\*\\*']
```

Please see me as novice in python

Answer (score 0):

You can check the `type` of `args["directories"]["dirname"]` and treat accordingly:

```
rules = []
dirnames = args["directories"]["dirname"]
if isinstance(dirnames, basestring):
    rules.append(os.path.join(dirnames, "*", "*"))
elif isinstance(dirnames, list):
    for v in dirnames:
        rules.append(os.path.join(v, "*", "*"))
```

Comment: what if I want to call the same function for both 'String' and 'list' type ? wouldn't it be a redudant code ?

Comment: @Debianeese Ah I see, check my answer again.  You wouldn't have redundant code because you need different behavior for each case.